# Send data stream to another classes

Tags: c#, silverlight, stream

Help to understand the essence of transfer data to another class.
So,Silverlight application.I have page Home.xaml(and its code-behind Home.xaml.cs).There is the button. when I click on the button the following code is executed:

**Home.xaml.cs**

```
        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendialog.Multiselect = true;
        bool? dialogResult = opendialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
        {

            Stream fileStream = opendialog.File.OpenRead();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
                      ............
```

here i need in such data as **reader** ,because i want this data stream(reader) to send to some completely another classes (for example, one *DataProccess.cs*):

**DataProccess.cs**:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1.Models
{
public static class DataProcess
{

    {

    }

}
```

that will process the data stream (**reader** from Home.xaml.cs) using regular expressions  and output data will  place into collection List<>.

how to implement it. I would be happy for a few lines of code from you? :)

**Revised code:**

**Home.xaml.cs:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendialog.Multiselect = true;
        bool? dialogResult = opendialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value)
        {
            Stream fileStream = opendialog.File.OpenRead();
            var processor = new Processor();
            ICollection<object> results = processor.Process(fileStream);
        }
    }
```

**Processor.cs**

```
 public class Processor
{
    public ICollection<object> Process(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string pattern = @"set vrouter ""([\w-]+)""";
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var matches =
                Regex.Matches(reader.ReadToEnd(), pattern)
                    .Cast<Match>().Where(m => m.Success)
                    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                    .Distinct();

            foreach (var match in matches)
            {
                var val = match + Environment.NewLine;
                return new Collection<object>().Add(val);;  //here error

            }

        }


        //return new Collection<object>(val);
    }
}
```

**such error:** 
Error1/Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'

Comment: the error is coming from your .Add(val). That is a void method. You should use `return new Collection<object> { val };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class that will process your results

```
public class Processor
{
    public ICollection<object> Process(Stream stream)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        // do stuff

        return new Collection<object>();
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of it and call the Process method

```
Stream fileStream = opendialog.File.OpenRead();
var processor = new Processor();
ICollection<object> results = processor.Process(fileStream);
```

Comment: Shawn Kendrot, Hello !I added the corrected code according to your instructions. Could indicate an error now?:)